# Clang-Tidy llvm-header-guard directory configuration

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, include-guards

Is there a way to remove the suggested computer specific path on the suggested llvm-header-guard string when running static analysis with clang-tidy?

For example the suggested header guard for the file (cls/math/matrix.hpp) is:
    _USERS_NAME_DESKTOP_PROJECT_SRC_CLS_MATH_MATRIX_HPP

But to avoid making this specific to my computer it should only be:
    _PROJECT_SRC_CLS_MATH_MATRIX_HPP

Is there a way to configure clang-tidy such that it suggests header guards starting from the /project/ directory rather than the /users/ directory?

I am using clang 5.0.0, running from cmake.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If so, please let me know how!

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry! My work around was to settle to creating a file template script.

Answer (score 6):

I've also had this problem for ages and finally figured it out, at least for public includes: clang-tidy assumes that headers are within a directory called `include`.

So, if your headers are like `/home/me/myproject/include/myproject/header.h` then it will work properly and recommend `MYPROJECT_HEADER_H`.  If it doesn't find an `include` directory to treat as the root, then it falls back to the absolute path.

So the solution for libraries is to use that structure (which is probably a good idea anyway).  I am still not sure about headers inside a project's source though.

Comment: "which is probably a good idea anyway" not if you have headers which you want to keep internal to your project, surely. It's often preferable to keep *MyApi.cpp* and *MyApi.h* together in a *src* folder away from externally-facing interfaces.

Comment: Sure, I just meant for public includes, obviously that doesn't apply for side-by-side headers and implementations.  I'm guessing this is a symptom of the check being implemented specifically for LLVM which doesn't do that.  It would be nice if it were more general, or at least better documented.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This test is almost very useful but instead is not much use at all.